# Why is my second VBA on my sheet not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA for another reason already in my sheet, however i want a VBA on the same sheet that now allows me to select multiple options on a drop down, please tell me why this does not work? I simply want column 20 to be the area that the 2nd VBA works on

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
If Target.Column = 1 Then
  If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
  End If
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True

Dim Newvalue As String

On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Column = 20 Then
    If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
    Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Newvalue = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        Oldvalue = Target.Value
        If Oldvalue = "" Then
            Target.Value = Newvalue
        Else
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
        End If
    End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57999277/edit) to include your code as text

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: You probably should get rid of the `exitHandler` and `Application.EnableEvents = True`, and then the duplicate `Application.EnableEvents = True` (2nd from the end).

Comment: ```On Error Resume Next``` Is almost never a good thing to have in your code.

Comment: Hi this has not worked and has also caused the 1st VBA to no longer work

Comment: @JodieDaniels Your code won't even run in its current state. The only reason it was working was because you had ```On Error Resume Next``` which does nothing but mask the issue, so it worked for the first chunk but just threw up errors, which it then ignored, until it hit the end sub.

Comment: You cannot use ```application.undo``` in the middle of a sub. It needs to be the first line. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.undo.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I am completely new to this and i simply used a tutorial which supplied the code, would anyone be able to assist in writing the correct code?

Comment: Possibly, though I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do in the second half.